# Stop next instance of VB.net app from raising window to the top

Tags: vb.net

I am playing around with Visual Studio and learned how to create a single instance vb.net app.

Now I want to give the app a command by re-running the exe with an argument and the sub `MyApplication_StartupNextInstance` handles everything great but the application window is raised to the top and steals focus.

So my question is, how do I relaunch a single instance app without having it raise itself to the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built into the event handler:

```
e.BringToForeground = False
```

Comment: You really shouldn't need Google for stuff like that.  If you want to know something about a type or member then you should go immediately to the MSDN documentation for that type or member.  Only if you can find what you want there should you resort to a more general web search.  In the case of events, it's a couple of clicks to get to the documentation for the type of the `e` parameter to find out what data is provided by the event.